# Running a docker image on dokku

Tags: docker, dokku

1) I know and have deployed many apps to dokku.

2) I know the whole git push to a subdomain process of dokku.

3) I also run images from docker by themselves and they run great.

4) I really cant seem to find an answer to this anywhere though. How can i run a DOCKER IMAGE in a DOKKU APP. As in i want that docker image to be running in a dokku app, not by itself using docker run. This is what i imagine:

```
dokku create:app myApp
<Now make that app run a Docker image, i DONT want to git push and build.>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

According to this: [Dokku Docs](http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/application-deployment/#) under **DockerFile deployment**, it looks like you place the DockerFile into the repo and push to dokku.

Comment: As one of the dokku maintainers, I can confirm that pushing an app with a Dockerfile is the correct way. You may also deploy by sending in a tar via stdin to the `tar:in` plugin if you *really* don't want to push to deploy, but that seems like more work.

Answer (score 5):

It's now supported to run docker images directly using `dokku git:from-image` command

Check this: [Dokku from docker image](https://dokku.com/docs/deployment/methods/git/#initializing-an-app-repository-from-a-docker-image)